# Are these alternative definitions of the "median" correct?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, examples-counterexamples, median

> (Textbook accepted) Definition: The median of a random variable X is any real value $m$
>   s.t. $P(X \geq m)\geq\frac{1}{2}$ and $P(X \leq m)\geq \frac{1}{2}$.

I've come up with 4 alternative definitions of the "median." I'm writing to ask whether those would also work against all counterexamples.

$(1)$

A "median" of a random variable X is any real value $m$
 s.t. $P(X \geq m) < \frac{1}{2}$ and $P(X \leq m) < \frac{1}{2}$.

$(2)$

A "median" of a random variable X is any real value $m$
 s.t. $P(X \geq m) < \frac{1}{2}$ and $P(X \leq m) \leq \frac{1}{2}$
.

$(3)$
A "median" of a random variable X is any real value $m$
 s.t. $P(X \geq m) \leq \frac{1}{2}$ and $P(X \leq m) \leq \frac{1}{2}$

$(4)$

A "median" of a random variable X is any real value $m$
 s.t. $P(X \geq m) \leq \frac{1}{2}$ and $P(X \leq m) < \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: "work against all counterexamples": all counterexamples ?

Comment: Suppose $X$ is always equal to 1. What values of $m$ satisfy each of your alternatives?

Comment: @SteveKass, for a degenerate random variable X always equal to one, $m=1$ satisfies all my alternatives. I don't think in your case a median exists.

Comment: It might be your translation, but then you might learn something about using language in mathematics, but I'd like to criticise the wording of the "accepted" definition: It does not make sense to define *the* ... as *any* ..., "the" signals that there is only one, "any" suggests that there might be more.

Comment: For $X$ always equal to $1$, your definition (1) (for example) is not satisfied. $P(X\ge 1)=1$, which is not less than $1\over2$. (Furthermore, the median of this $X$ should certainly be $1$, and it is, according to the textbook definition.)

Comment: To reiterate Henrik’s comment: medians are not necessarily unique, just something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For *every* $m\in\mathbb R$ we have:$$P(X\geq m)+P(X\leq m)=P(X=m)+1\geq1\tag1$$Now draw conclusions for (1),(2) and (4).

Concerning (3):

Note that $(1)$ implies that the "median" defined this way is forced to take a value $m$ such that $P(X=m)=0$, so it will not always coincide with what is normally called the median.

Comment: can you give a counterexample of why $"3"$ doesn't work?

Comment: Let $P(X=0)=1$. Then the median is $0$ because $P(X\geq0)=1\geq1/2$ and $P(X\leq0)=1\geq1/2$. But we do not have $P(X\geq0)\leq1/2$ and $P(X\leq0)\leq1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a particular reason to accept asymmetric definitions. Then number (1) must be rejected as it will result in "no median" if the $\text{cdf}$ takes the value $\frac12$.